# Audio power amplifier circuit explaination

Tags: amplifier, audio, analog

This circuit:

[image: circuit]

My goal is to modify this circuit to operate in DC mode.

Got this circuit on the web, but there is some part of it that I still don't get how it operates.

T4/T5 is an adjustable current source, but I get lost down the path T1, T2, T6, T8 and also the impact of R11/R13. Changing values of C6 and C7 appear to change the gain which is quite surprising.

Is VR1 supposed to adjust the amplification gain ?

Comment: No. VR1 adjust the balance of the input differential, essentially a DC offset control. Normally DC amplifiers employ a op-amp integrator that feeds DC offset in the output back to the input such that capacitors are not needed. Only a skilled engineer could and should do this. This looks to be a 600 watt amplifier. If it works, don't fix it...

Comment: It does work, I just need a slightly different usage. I've been able to convert it to DC and works fine, but still want to understand a bit more the circuit itself. You refer as such capacitor not needed if the DC offset is feeded back through an opamp, which cap are you referring to ? @Sparky256

Comment: To explain it in detail would take many pages of text. It is 5:00 AM here and way past my bedtime. Someone else here should understand the details.

Comment: So how did you convert it, if you say that it works?

Comment: Removing the input decoupling cap, and adjusting some values on the filter before T3. @MarkoBuršič. Although while on positive side it's clean, the negative side output is noisy under load.

Comment: Actually the filtero on base of T3 is the feedback loop 33:1, which is also high pass, as input on T1. You should remove also C6. VR1 is a offset setting, at 0V on input you want to get 0V at output. Perhaps you get clean positive output, but not sure if the amplitude is exactly the Vin*Gain.

Comment: I've set C6 to 1uF and removed R11 (C6 connected to T1 and GND), if I remove C6 the circuit becomes unstable. What sets the gain of the circuit ? currently it seems to be 2.

Comment: The gain is set by resitor divider R13 and R11. 1k/(33k+1k)=1/34 so G=34, but you have also an input attenuator 33/34, finnaly 33*34/34 = 33, overall gain is 33. You may not eliminate the R13,R11. Only short C6 as you done with C1, but don't blame me if get smoked the amp.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful, I modified the circuit accordingly and the gain match. There is still a bit of noise under load but this will wait Monday. Do you have suggestion to improve the circuit (remove gain/offset error) using a feedback with an opamp or is that useless?

Comment: First of all, you should state what is the final goal of this modification. Only then, you would probably need to post a second answer is how to modify to suit your demand: Flat response, high bandwidth, or low frequency stable working. The key is in the caps C2, C7, new C6 parallel to R11....

Comment: When removing C6, replace it with a short.  If you leave it open, you won't get any gain.

Comment: Remove C1 and C6. Source T1 and T2 from a shared-substrate diffpair such as HA/CA3046, originally from RCA but now from Harris. Keep R4 and R9 (the collector gain resistors in very close thermal proximity, and keep any heat flows very small and parallel to the bodies of R4 and R9.